# Performing bitwise left shifts on "signed" data in Java -- better to move to JNI?

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface, byte, bit-manipulation

I've been asking questions on hex and bitwise manipulation (here and elsewhere) for the past week trying to wrap my head around their representation in Java. After much Googling and chagrin I must ask one final time how to perform logical arithmetic on bits that ought to be unsigned, but are represented as signed in Java.

Okay: I am porting a C# program to Java. The program deals with bitmap manipulation, and as such much of the data in the app is represented as **`byte`**, an unsigned 8-bit integer. There are many suggestions to instead use the `short` data type in Java in order to "mimic" as close as possible the unsigned 8-byte integer.

I don't believe that's possible for me as the C# code is performing various many shifting and AND operations with my byte data. For example, if `data` is a byte array, and this block of code exists in C#:

```
int cmdtype = data[pos] >> 5;
int len = (data[pos] & 0x1F) + 1;

if (cmdtype == 7)
{
    cmdtype = (data[pos] & 0x1C) >> 2;
    len = ((data[pos] & 3) << 8) + data[pos + 1] + 1;
    pos++;
}
```

It's not a simple matter of just casting `data` as a `short` and being done with it to get it to work in Java. As far as the logic is concerned the requirement that my data stay in 8-bit unsigned is significant; 16-bit unsigned would screw math like the above up. Am I right here? Indeed, after having previously "fake casting" `byte` with `0XFF` and `char` in Java and not getting the right results, I am afraid I hit a dead end.

Now, in another part of the code, I am performing some bitmap pixel manipulation. Since it's a long running process, I decided to make a call to native code through JNI. I realized recently that in there I could use the `uint8_t` data type and get the closest representation to the C# `byte` data type.

Is the solution to make all my data-dependent functionality operate in JNI? That seems highly inefficient, both to rewrote and to perform. Is the solution to redo the math in Java so the logic remains the same? That *seems* right, but has the potential to induce an aneurysm, not to mention faulty math.

I appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: Could you add comments indicating what C# does versus what Java does at each step in the code snippet?  I don't think I can puzzle out all the spots in that code where you might be seeing problems by myself.

Comment: I don't have anything I would classify as an answer, but if you are doing a lot of bit twiddling, I suggest writing a simple class using JNI that does this rather than doing a lot of casting. That will hurt performance, debuggability, and readability. Regardless, I would still profile the code before converting everything to JNI. Focus on the areas that need it most.

Comment: @John I am not proposing to redo it all in JNI--I was just wondering if that was a viable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a note: You cannot cast directly to `short`, because negative numbers will be logically extended.

That is, the byte `1111 1101` (-5) when directly cast to `short` will result in `1111 1111 1111 1101` (-5), not `0000 0000 1111 1101` (253). You must remove the leading ones with an AND operation when you cast:

```
short shortValue = ((short)(byteValue)) & 0xFF;
```

I know complex bit manipulation like this is possible, because I have done this exact thing in handling a legacy binary messaging protocol with a Java Swing application. I would highly recommend somehow abstracting this away so that you only have to deal with it once. Whether that means wrapping your "bytes" in a class to store them as shorts and handle the conversion operations, or defining a static utility that does the conversion and bit operation in one pass, so that you always store bytes.

Comment: I think my brain is just fried. if I do the flip and the cast will my bitwise math stay the same? As I said previously, I was "fake casting" with the exact technique you described, only using a char instead.

Answer (score 2):

Java has the `>>>` (note the three ">" characters, not just two) unsigned right-shift operator.  This should keep the C# style right-shifting at least (upper bits are cleared to zero, not sign-filled).

As far as casting to a 'short', C# casts all those bytes to 32-bit integers before shifting anyway.  The only trick is, C# does an unsigned cast (just fills upper 24 bits with 0s, regardless of the value of bit 7).  If you did cast to short in Java, you should just be able to say something like:

```
short shortCast = ( (short)byteVal ) & 0xff;
short shiftedShortCast = shortCast << whatever;
```

Comment: It's true that C# converts to an `int`, but it also has the concept of unsigned types, which keep leading ones from extending in what would be negative numbers.